# Finish two activities on receive the same broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which handles System Broadcasts like AC Connected and disconnected. The `BroadcastReceiver` receives `POWER_CONNECTED` and starts an Activity "MainActivity", which unlocks `KeyGuard` and acquires `WakeLock`. In the `onCreate` and in `onResume` I register dynamically a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen on `POWER_DISCONNECTED`.

The "MainActivity" starts a second "VideoPlayer Activity", which also register a `BroadcastReceiver` listening on `POWER_DISCONNECTED`.

When I send the `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECT` over adb I see through LogCat that the "MainActivity" stops first. Why?

How can I handle that the "VideoPlayerActivity" finishes first?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> Normal broadcasts (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely asynchronous. **All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order**, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.

You can't guarantee that VideoPlayerActivity will receive.

I would recommend to create a separate BroadcastReceiver (which isn't part of activities). And in this broadcast receiver do something like this:

```
videoPlayerActivity.finish();
mainActivity.finish();
```

Sure, you need to initialize both of these variables in onCreate or onResume of your activities.

Comment: The both activities have their own Receiver implemented as inner classes. Perhaps its possible to stop the second started activity with a custom broadcast so it is independant from the POWER_CONNECTED intent. I would consume this broadcast in the first one but send a custom broadcast which would be consumed by the second receiver in the second activity. So i could tell him to finish. And after sending the custom broadcast i would finish the main activity within the onReceive method. I'll try this.

Comment: I think what you described should work. However, I just don't like combining BroadcastReceiver's and Activities in one entity. The main reason for this is Single responsibility principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I agree with you. But how I can solve this, when I don't know the Instance of this both activities. The Brodcastreceivers in their own classes are independant from the activities.

Comment: All you need to do is to save instances of these two activities in oCreate/oResume of each activity. You can save them to some static members or create a standalone class with static members. Later on broadcastactivity can read it from these static members.

Comment: I solved the problem by giving the created receivers a priority. The Sub Activity gets a higher prio=2 and the main gets prio=1. It works, but the Problem after this was, thar the Sub Activity consumes the broadcast. The Main Activity never catchs the broadcast. The only way and I think the best (?) was catch the broadcast in the Main Activity and send a custom broadcast to the Sub Activity, just before finishing the Main Activity. This helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you Registered the Broadcast Receiver in your main activity so its passing the context of main activity in the BroadcastReceiver so i will able to finish only that activity.

So lets screw up this what you need to do just write these lines of code in the **onReceive()** of **Power Disconnected** action receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Enjoy